# How to convert a Java Object to a JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, json

i need to convert a POJO to a JSONObject (org.json.JSONObject)

I know how to convert it to a file:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(new File(file.toString()), registrationData);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I dont want a file this time.

Comment: There are a lot of libraries for it: Jackson, Jettison. You also could use JAXB with MOXy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's not a too complex object, you can **do it yourself**, without any libraries. Here is an example how:

```
public class DemoObject {

    private int mSomeInt;
    private String mSomeString;

    public DemoObject(int i, String s) {

        mSomeInt = i;
        mSomeString = s;
    }

    //... other stuff

    public JSONObject toJSON() {

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("integer", mSomeInt);
        jo.put("string", mSomeString);

        return jo;
    }
}
```

In code:

```
DemoObject demo = new DemoObject(10, "string");
JSONObject jo = demo.toJSON();
```

Of course you can also use [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for more complex stuff and a less cumbersome implementation if you don't mind the extra dependency.

Comment: I ended up doing somethng like this :)

Comment: Change the last line to JsonObject=gson.toJson(demo) not demo.toJson()

Answer (score 40):

If we are parsing all model classes of server in [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) format then this is a best way to convert java object to `JSONObject.In` below code `SampleObject` is a java object which gets converted to the `JSONObject`.

```
SampleObject mSampleObject = new SampleObject();
String jsonInString = new Gson().toJson(mSampleObject);
JSONObject mJSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonInString);
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest, easiest and efficient way :)

Answer (score 11):

The example below was pretty much lifted from [mkyongs tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/). Instead of saving to a file you can just use the `String json` as a json representation of your POJO.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        YourObject obj = new YourOBject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(obj); //convert 
        System.out.println(json);

    }
}
```

Comment: do I need a Gson library for this?

Comment: Yes you need to add Google's gson library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to convert Java object to JSON Object (not Json String)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
            
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(JavaObject));
```

Comment: JSONValue is belongs which package ?

Comment: It's should be: ```JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(JavaObject));```

Answer (score 1):

How to get JsonElement from Object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.*;    

final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(source);
JsonElement result = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
```